# Access correct counter when asynchronous function is called

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, protractor

I am trying to store data in an array in a ordered way, here in the code I am trying to get row by row using the DOM, the problem is that getText() is asynchronous function and the execute is not in the order I expect, how can I access the correct value of counter1 when the then() called?

```
for(var counter1 = 0;counter1<length;counter1++) {

       rows[counter1].all(by.css("div:nth-child(1)")).getText().then(function(row){
             arr[counter1] = row;  //the value is the length for all calls
       });
}
```

Comment: are you using some kind of library (like jquery or such) ?

Comment: I am using protractor.